# How to add a comma delimiter to the beginning of the city in an address

Tags: excel, cell

Example:

```
1412 Chestnut Street Philadelphia
494 W Germantown Pike Plymouth Meeting
```

I would like to add a comma to the beginning of each city in a list of 200 but as you can see above sometimes the city name does not start at the last word in the cell.

Is there an overarching formula that could add a comma before `Philadelphia` and `Plymouth Meeting`?

Comment: You mean, how to do it in MS Excel?

Comment: Not without more information.  I can't tell where the street name ends and the city begins in `494 W Germantown Pike Plymouth Meeting`.  Do you have a separate list of cities that appear in your list?

Comment: I would like it to end up 494 W Germantown Pike, Plymouth Meeting or 494 W Germantown Pike,Plymouth Meeting; so I can use text to column and seperate by comma(or any delimter other than space for that matter).

Comment: Example: 185 North West End Boulevard Quakertown ////                                                      Generally the city is found in the last word but like the "Plymouth Meeting" example it is the last two words

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that you can adapt to your use.  Say We have addresses in column **A** and the city list in column **B**:

[image]

The following macro scans the addresses looking for a *[space][city]* and replaces the city with *[,][city]*

```
Sub Commafication()
   Dim Acol As String, Ccol As String
   Dim ia As Long, ic As Long, va As String, vc As String

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'  update these as needed
Acol = "A"
Ccol = "B"
iamax = 3
icmax = 6
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   For ia = 1 To iamax
      va = Cells(ia, Acol).Text
      For ic = 1 To icmax
         vc = Cells(ic, Ccol).Text
         If InStr(va, " " & vc) > 0 Then
            Cells(ia, Acol).Value = Replace(va, vc, "," & vc)
         End If
      Next ic
   Next ia
End Sub
```

Here is the result:

[image]

***NOTE***

This places the comma before the city name, as you requested, rather than placing a space between the comma and the city.